# How to add a parameter to <a> links in the nav menu?

Tags: menus, navigation

I have to add `itemprop="url"` to the  links of the links in the navbar of [this site](http://www.anahatatantra.com/).

In the settings I found the function `wp_nav_menu()`. Even after reading the WP codex, I am not able to make the necessary changes by myself.

Here is the code:

```
<!-- BEGIN MAIN NAVIGATION -->
<nav class="nav nav__primary clearfix">
<?php if (has_nav_menu('header_menu')) {
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'container'      => 'ul',
        'menu_class'     => 'sf-menu',
        'menu_id'        => 'topnav',
        'depth'          => 0,
        'theme_location' => 'header_menu',
        'walker'         => new description_walker()
    ));
} else {
    echo '<ul class="sf-menu">';
        $ex_page = get_page_by_title( 'Privacy Policy' );
        if ($ex_page === NULL) {
            $ex_page_id = '';
        } else {
            $ex_page_id = $ex_page->ID;
        }
        wp_list_pages( array(
            'depth'    => 0,
            'title_li' => '',
            'exclude'  => $ex_page_id
            )
        );
    echo '</ul>';
} ?>
</nav><!-- END MAIN NAVIGATION -->
```

And here is the Walker class:

```
/*
 * Navigation with description
 *
 */
if (! class_exists('description_walker')) {
    class description_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        global $wp_query;
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
        $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

        $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'>';

        // $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        // $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
        // $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
        // $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

        $atts = array();
        $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
        $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )     ? $item->target     : '';
        $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';
        $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url )        ? $item->url        : '';

        /**
         * Filter the HTML attributes applied to a menu item's <a>.
         *
         * @since 3.6.0
         *
         * @see wp_nav_menu()
         *
         * @param array $atts {
         *     The HTML attributes applied to the menu item's <a>, empty strings are ignored.
         *
         *     @type string $title  Title attribute.
         *     @type string $target Target attribute.
         *     @type string $rel    The rel attribute.
         *     @type string $href   The href attribute.
         * }
         * @param object $item The current menu item.
         * @param array  $args An array of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         */
        $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args );

        $attributes = '';
        foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
            if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
                $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
            }
        }

        $description  = ! empty( $item->description ) ? '<span class="desc">'.esc_attr( $item->description ).'</span>' : '';

        if($depth != 0) {
            $description = $append = $prepend = "";
        }

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before;

        if (isset($prepend))
            $item_output .= $prepend;

        $item_output .= apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );

        if (isset($append))
            $item_output .= $append;

        $item_output .= $description.$args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
}
```

So the final links will look like this:

```
<li id="menu-item-2005" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a itemprop="url" title="thetitle" href="http://thesite.com/about-us/">About Us</a></li>
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Worst case, you can always write you're own custom walker - https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker

Comment: I think there is a Walker already. I just added it above. I just don't know what to edit there to add that parameter.

Answer (score 1):

To add a new attribute to your anchor link for the nav items concatenate $attribute variable with your required attribute. You have commended code just uncomment the code and use those

```
     $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_atta( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
     $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_atto( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
     $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
     $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';
     $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' itemprop="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

    //$atts = array();
    //$atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
    //$atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )     ? $item->target     : '';
    //$atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';
    //$atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url )        ? $item->url        : '';
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The change to be done is to change:

```
$item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
```

to

```
$item_output .= '<a itemprop=url'. $attributes .'>';
```

Comment: Why this -1 ? It works fine this solution.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's probably because it isn't the cleanest solution.